# Nodejs how to use Multer on function

Tags: node.js, express

I have created controller, routes and functions base api. What issue I am getting is how can I use Multer on function.

I have function like this

```
const { Users } = require('../models/user');
const { Company } = require('../models/company');
const { Jobs } = require('../models/job');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const multer = require('multer');

const FILE_TYPE_MAP = {
    'image/png': 'png',
    'image/jpeg': 'jpeg',
    'image/jpg': 'jpg'
};

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        const isValid = FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
        let uploadError = new Error('invalid image type');

        if (isValid) {
            uploadError = null;
        }
        cb(uploadError, 'public/uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const fileName = file.originalname.split(' ').join('-');
        const extension = FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
        cb(null, `${fileName}-${Date.now()}.${extension}`);
    }
});

const uploadOptions = multer({ storage: storage });




const createJob = function async(req, res) {
    const job = new Jobs({
        jobTitle: req.body.jobTitle,
        jobDescription: req.body.jobDescription,
        jobImage: req.body.userType,
        jobType: req.body.jobType,
        jobNumberOfPeople: req.body.jobNumberOfPeople,
        jobHireTime: req.body.jobHireTime,
        jobMinPay: req.body.jobMinPay,
        jobMaxPay: req.body.jobMaxPay,
        jobday: req.body.jobday,
        jobRecieveApplication: req.body.jobRecieveApplication,
        jobSubmitResume: req.body.jobSubmitResume,
        jobApplicationDeadline: req.body.jobApplicationDeadline,
        jobCommunationSetting: req.body.jobCommunationSetting,
        jobMessageSetting: req.body.jobMessageSetting,
        companyID: req.body.companyID,
    });

    try {
        const jobsave = await job.save();

        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: jobsave })
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
            console.error(Object.values(err.errors).map(val => val.message))
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: Object.values(err.errors).map(val => val.message)[0] })
        }
        res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: err })
    }
};

module.exports = { createJob };
```

and routes like this

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/user');
const jobController = require('../controllers/jobs');

router.post('/createJob', jobController.createJob);

module.exports = router;
```

now I need to add `uploadOptions.single('jobImage')` in function

I am doing like this const createJob =

```
const createJob = uploadOptions.single('jobImage'), async(req, res) => { };
```

Its showing this error on comma don't know why

[image]

Its working directly on router but I need to do In function

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
module.exports = {
  createJob : [ uploadOptions.single('jobImage'), createJob ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks but How to use this in router or controller ?

Comment: This is the only change you have to make to get it working with the code you're showing.